# Extend Collection: Array and Set, but not Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, collections, set

```
extension Array {
    init?<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S?) where S.Element == Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return nil }
        self.init(sequence)
    }
}

extension Set {
    init?<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S?) where S.Element == Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return nil }
        self.init(sequence)
    }
}
```

As you can see the code in both extensions is absolutely identical. So how can I rewrite it without repetitiveness? Something like:

```
extension Collection where type == Array || type == Set {
    init?<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S?) where S.Element == Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return nil }
        self.init(sequence)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sweeper Ok, and how to do that?

Comment: Actually we don't need such an initializer. The code: sequence.map(Array.init) has the same effect.

Comment: yes, but I still like an initialiser better. It just seems “more direct” :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialiser you want to add to `Array`s and `Set`s can in fact be added to all `Sequences`, because you are not using anything that is unique in `Array` or `Set`. All that the initialiser depends on is:

- having an `Element` associated type
- having an initialiser that takes a `Sequence`

[`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) satisfies the first criteria, and there is no common protocol between `Array` and `Set` that satisfies the second :-(. The one from `Array` comes from [`RangeReplaceableCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection). The one from `Set` comes from [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/setalgebra).

You can create such a protocol yourself though:

```
protocol SequenceInitialisable : Sequence {
    init<S: Sequence>(_ s: S) where S.Element == Element
}

extension Array : SequenceInitialisable {}
extension Set : SequenceInitialisable {}

extension SequenceInitialisable {
    init?<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S?) where S.Element == Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return nil }
        self.init(sequence)
    }
}
```

Or ([as you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63610684/extend-collection-array-and-set-but-not-dictionary?noredirect=1#comment113690019_63610684)) you can just do `sequence.map(Array.init)` if you don't mind writing `map` and `init`.

---

A tip on writing extensions: Try to find all the things that your extension depends on/needs, and then find the *most general type* that has all of those things. That is the type you should write the extension on.

Comment: I've just spot a problem with this solution. It doesn't work. It causes infinite recursive calls of our custom initializer. Sequence doesn't have any initializers that we can use after unwrapping the optional.

Comment: @Roman really? I recall that Sequence does have a initialiser just like the one in my answer, except it is not failable and accepts a non-optional. I’m currently outside, so I’ll try it out when I get back, but I certainly remember that I confirmed this worked 2 months ago...

Comment: @Roman I can't believe I made this mistake! My brain must not have been working that day! Fixed with a not-so-elegant solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
protocol NilSequenceInitializable {}

extension NilSequenceInitializable where Self: Sequence {
    init?<S: Sequence>(_ sequence: S?) where S.Element == Element {
        guard let sequence = sequence else { return nil }
        self.init(sequence)
    }
}

extension Array: NilSequenceInitializable {}
extension Set: NilSequenceInitializable {}
```